# what IC is typically used in a switched mode power supply for pwm voltage regulation

Tags: integrated-circuit, pwm, timer

So what is used? do they basically run off of a something like a 555?

Comment: I've seen some that don't even seem to have a pwm circuit

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no prior research effort. Try googling this: https://www.google.com/search?q=switch+mode+regulator&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivncud6dHJAhVItBQKHYDOD6cQ_AUICCgC&biw=1289&bih=901 and counting the ways and the chips.

Comment: Making silly assumptions about how products are implemented and assuming they're all using 555 timers since that's the only IC YOU know is a bad way to learn about electronics. There is so much to learn if you just look for it. If you're unwilling to spent that time and learn about it before asking silly questions then maybe electronics is not for you.

Comment: I could learn by asking. WHAT!! And I did do a little research but the answer to my question was not obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a "typically" used IC anymore.  There are hundreds of choices these days and I don't think there's a single professional power supply designer that would consider the 555.

One of the old standards for current mode control is the UC3842:

[UC3842](http://www.ti.com/product/uc3842)

However, that part is now dated and there are many better choices depending on the specifics of what you want to accomplish.

Check the websites of companies like TI, Intersil, Maxim and LT to get a feel for what's available.